# How to modify Column stacked percent Chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[image: This is what I want]
I want to change the functionality of this chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent

in such a way that, when i click on the legend the percentage that is being calculated should be formulated from all the data series rather than just the visible ones. Right now clicking on legend it the column always becomes 100%.

Comment: you want tooltip to show `current hover` vs all data percentage or `current hover color` vs all data percentage

Comment: @Siddharth What I want is on clicking on the legend item, the bar should not be shown on the chart but at the same time the percentage values should not change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set [`ignoreHiddenSeries`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.ignoreHiddenSeries) to `false`, but in that case hiding series other than the top one will not make other series fall down to fill the gap in the stack.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pahyq9b9/

Another solution would be to parse your data and use `normal` stacking instead of `percent`, because normal stacking will only move other points and will not change point values.

Comment: This is what I wanted, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gatugko7/), what i have done is i have used `formatter` instead of `pointformat`

```
  tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s=0;
            var r="<span>"+this.x+"</span><br/>"


            $.each(this.points, function (i,v) {
                console.log(v);

                r+='<span style="color:'+v.color+'">'+v.series.name+'</span>: <b>   '+v.y+'</b>  '+((v.y*100)/total)+'% <br/>'
            });

            console.log(r);
            return r;

        },
        shared:true
    },
```

and more to this i have added some global variables

```
var obj=Highcharts.charts[$("#container").data('highchartsChart')]; 

var total=0;
for(v of obj.options.series){
    for(z of v.data){
    total+=z;
  }
}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: Ya I just saw, you are very close to understanding my question. Please refer this image : http://i.imgur.com/Cdta5L2.png . When I click on any of the legends, the bar should be removed from displaying that's it.

Comment: can u add this image to original question?

Comment: that URL is also blocked in my office :( man just add the image to original question